# CouchDB + Datamapper + View = no ids

Tags: javascript, ruby, couchdb, datamapper

I'm using couchdbx v. 0.8.1 and datamapper 0.9.8. I've written a few simple views, copied some from other examples. If I query the views with a browser they return id's. If I query them using datamapper in ruby I get no id's. I've googled for days, been on IRC and looked through the couch and datamapper google groups. I've tried downgrading my datamapper and couchdb. Nothing. Anyone else run into this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I see that there is a couchdb adapter for datamapper (dm-couchdb-adapter), but I'm not familiar with it.  Are you sure that you need to be using an ORM for accessing CouchDB?  There are a few ruby libraries that may be better suited to accessing CouchDB, e.g. [CouchRest](http://github.com/jchris/couchrest/tree/master).

You should note that the Google group for CouchDB is now dead.  You should try asking on the mailing list users@couchdb.apache.org.  These are the archives: [Graduated](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/couchdb-user/); [Incubator](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-couchdb-user/) There are plenty of people there that have experience using CouchDB with Ruby and should be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: I agree with the notion of not requiring something like DataMapper in the middle.  I'm not too familiar with CouchRest, but I use couchdb-python directly from my web apps.